# Add a string to a Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
movie_list=[]
movie_list.extend(movieid[1])
print movieid
print movie_list
```

I got the following output:

```
(832871, 'Espas en Hollywood')
['E', 's', 'p', 'a', 's', ' ', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'H', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'd']
```

Why did I get a character list as a result of append? What should I do if I  'd like to attach the string 'Espas en Hollywood' to movie_list?

i.e desired output:

```
['Espas en Hollywood']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`append`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> movie_list = []
>>> movie_list.append('Espas en Hollywood')
>>> movie_list
['Espas en Hollywood']
```

If you want to use **`extend`**:

```
movie_list.append(['Espas en Hollywood'])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend

Comment: string is treated as a list

Comment: @qwt185 - A python string is essentially an array of single letters. For example `"hello"[1] == 'e'`